# Spark Application Testing: Initialize variable in object with different file in Production and Test Env

Tags: scala, apache-spark, junit, spark-streaming

I am working on a spark application. While writing test cases for application , i came across requirement where i need to initialize a var in object with different file rather than production file. For ex:

```
ObjA{
   val properties: Properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(new FileInputStream("constants.properties"))
    val map = JavaConverters.propertiesAsScalaMapConverter(properties).asScala
}
```

In Test enviornment i wanted to use a different file other than `constants.properties` . i.e i wanted to initialize objA with file `constant.properties` present in test directory. I dont want to pass file name as argument to method. Is there a way where application figures out env(Test or production) and initialize variable as per that?

Thanks

Comment: how about using driver ip for env decisions ?

Comment: I didnt get you . How Driver ip can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use ip from driver  (node you submit application). Before, initializing sparkContext finding you test env ip, you could do some thing like below,

```
import java.net._

val ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost
val props = if (ip == "ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ec2.internal") "TestConstant.properties" else "productionConstants.properties"
properties.load(new FileInputStream("props"))
```

so, in test env it is gonna load test property in any other env it is gonna load prod property

Comment: Thanks .Its a solution  , but it will not work in all situation. We will be testing in different machines and ip will not be fixed . I was thinking more form dependency injection point of view, if there could be any similar situation

Comment: uw. When you say _Is there a way where application figures out env(Test or production) and initialize variable as per that_ what do you mean by that? is there any possibility apart from ip to identify where you are at?